# Rolling average of values that satisfy multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, rolling-computation

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so please bear with me if I make any mistakes or omit necessary information.

I have a dataset consisting of a time series where I need to find the 5-day rolling average of a binary variable for each specific hour of the day. An example of my data can be created using:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

set.seed(69)
df <- data.frame(Hour = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), times = 10),
                 Reg = rep(round(runif(24*10, 0, 1))),
                 HumidityLevel = rep(runif(24*10, 0, 100)))

df_ranges <- data.frame(LowerRange = rep(cbind(rollapply(df$HumidityLevel, 24, min, by = 24)), each = 24)
                        ,UpperRange = rep(cbind(rollapply(df$HumidityLevel, 24, max, by = 24)), each = 24))

df <- cbind(df, df_ranges)
```

I have computed the simple rolling average using the following code:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Hour) %>% 
  mutate(AvgReg = lag(rollapplyr(Reg, 5, mean, na.rm = T, partial = T), n = 1))
```

What I need to do is compute the rolling average of Reg using previous rows where HumidityLevel lies within the range for that specific day. The lower and upper boundary of the range is determined by two columns (LowerRange, UpperRange). The boundary values are dependent on the lowest and highest HumidityLevel-values for the day.

For instance, a day may have levels between 20 and 54. The rolling average for hour 1 of that specific day should then be computed by using previous Hour 1 observations with a HumidityLevel value above or equal to 20 and below or equal to 54.

I hope that my question makes sense.

This is my desired output:

```
desired_output <- data.frame(RowNum = c(1:10),
                  Hour = rep(1, times = 10),
                  Reg = c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                  HumidityLevel = c(28.36, 65.02, 1.12, 49.61, 24.50, 98.16, 77.33, 97.03, 47.03, 85.71),
                  LowerBoundary = c(5.67, 7.50, 1.12, 19.32, 0.01, 6.94, 7.48, 0.71, 2.85, 1.59),
                  UpperBoundary = c(93.60, 89.37, 97.25, 99.63, 91.92, 98.16, 98.48, 99.98, 99.70, 98.86),
                  AvgReg = c("NA", 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2))
```

Comment: Nice first post but please include the library() calls of the relevant packages you use

Comment: Good point. I will add that right away!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` you can use `between` for filter and `shift` + `frollmean` for calculation:

```
setDT(df)[
  between(HumidityLevel, LowerRange, UpperRange),
  new_col := shift(
    frollmean(Reg, c(seq_len(min(5, .N)), rep(5, max(0, .N - 5))), adaptive = TRUE)
  ),
  by = Hour
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The provided code does not seem to provide the desired result. For instance, new_col in row 4 is equal to 0.33 whereas the output should be 0.5. The HumidityLevel of row 3 is equal to 1.12. Hence, it is outside the range of row 4 (19.32-99.63) and excluded from the computation of row 4's average.